# Generating nested JSON for incoming object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following class

```
public class Foo {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private Bar d;
}
```

For this, I want to generate following JSON

```
{
    "values":
    {
        "value_id":"<value_of_field_a>"
    },
    "bar":
    {
        "id":"<value_of_field_b>",
        "object":
        {
            "<value_of_bar_object_d>"
        }
    }
    "seq":"<value_of_field_c>"
}
```

Yes, I can create a pojo which will mimic this hierarchy but the example i posted here is way simpler than the actual object. is there a way i can generate custom hierarchy for JSON using Jackson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a custom serializer:

```
public class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("values");
        jgen.writeStringField("value_id", value.getA());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
        // TODO: serialize the other fields
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Register the custom serializer by annotating `Foo` with `@JsonSerialize`:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
public class Foo {
...
}
```